# Stop AppleScript Running .jar When Java Error Raised

Tags: java, applescript

I have an AppleScript which I am using to run a .jar file. The .jar file takes several inputs which were originally entered via the command line but now I enter into a .csv and get read into the .jar automatically. For unknown reasons, sometimes a number in the CSV is not read correctly leading to a `NumberFormatException` in the Java code. However, instead of breaking, my script continually tries to enter the invalid input in an infinite loop. Is there a way to amend my code so that when an error is raised by the .jar, the script stops?

Here is my current code:

```
on RunFile(jar_location)
    do shell script "cd " & jar_location & " ; cat 'prompt.csv' | sh 'runScript.sh' 'WSO'"
end RunFile
```

Comment: Does the error percolate up to AppleScript? In other words, do you get an error that stops the AppleScript, while the shell script keep plugging away? It would be good to know: (1) whether this 'runScript.sh' is a one-shot, that runs quickly through its commands and returns to applescript, so that the main loop is in AppleScript, or (2) whether this is a continuing process something that detaches and runs separately from AppleScript.

Comment: @TedWrigley I believe the AppleScript keeps running and the process runs separately. If I were to enter an invalid input running the .jar from Terminal, Terminal would return "Invalid input" and prompt me to re-enter an input. The infinite loop is occurring through terminal.

Comment: Typically, if a shell script throws an error, that error would be handed off to AppleScript where we could work with it. But it doesn't sound like your shell script is throwing an error. It sounds like the shell is trying to work in interactive mode. If you want to handle this with AppleScript, you're going to have to get the .jar to work silently (throw errors rather than ask for input). Is that an option?

Comment: @TedWrigley The .jar is unfortunately a black box. Do you see any work around to this?

Comment: Well, you're not going to find a *real* solution unless you find out whether the .jar can be run non-interactively. Are there docs, or do you know the developer? The only hack I can offer is that you detach the process entirely and collect its process id. You do that with this change: `set pid to do shell script "... &> /dev/null & echo $!"`Once you detach the process the AppleScript will continue on, and then you can delay an appropriate time and then kill the process later if it's still running, using `do shell script "kill " & pid"`.

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html

Comment: I discovered my issue. Excel VBA was adding a leading space with its Str() method

Comment: I think your solution would work, so feel free to submit it as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going over this in the comments, it's clear that the problem is that the .jar file is trying to be interactive — asking for some input at the cursor — and AppleScript's `do shell script` is not designed for that. AppleScript can get errors and outputs form the shell, but it cannot feed a response back to the shell, or tell if a shell script is waiting for input.

if the .jar file cannot be operated in a non-interactive mode, then the only for AppleScript to make sure the process ends is to grab its process id number, wait a reasonable amount of time, and then send it a kill signal.  That script would look like this:

```
on RunFile(jar_location)
    set pid to do shell script "cd " & jar_location & " ; cat 'prompt.csv' | sh 'runScript.sh' 'WSO' &> /dev/null & echo $!"
    -- wait 5 seconds, or whatever seems appropriate for the task to complete
    delay 5
    try
        do shell script "kill " & pid
    end try
end RunFile
```

The appended `&> /dev/null & echo $!` phrase detaches the shell script, allowing the AppleScript to move forward, and returns the process id of the process for later use. I've put the kill signal in a try block so that the script does not throw an error if the process has already exited normally.